# Display sub-directories in Video Lens

Tags: unity, video, unity-dash, directory

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04 to try out.  I'm really liking the Unity Dash for easily opening content (HTPC in mind).

I decided to see how it works and I dumped a folder full of video files of my favourite show into Video's in my home folder, each season separated by directories.  When I went back to the Unity Dash, it mixed all the video's together.  I understand I could just search for the video I want, but I'd like to have the functionality to have things organized in sub-directories and click through what I want via Unity.  Is there a way to tell it to recognize the directory structure in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

I think the lens is more of a searcher than an organiser and a link to open a folder
would do this better, however could always make a feature request at https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-videos